# retrieve disk space from remote computers using powershell scripting

Tags: excel, powershell, shell, diskspace

get-WmiObject win32_logicaldisk -Computername remotecomputer

in this command what is this remotecomputer parameter? is it a text file then what kind of things i have to store there?

Answer (score 0):

In this command it's computer name, example:

```
get-WmiObject win32_logicaldisk -Computername JohnComp -Credential domainadmin@domain.com
```

You can also format output for this

```
get-WmiObject win32_logicaldisk -Computername JohnComp -Credential domainadmin@domain.com|select deviceid,devicetype,@{n="TotalSize / GB";e={($_.size / 1GB)}},@{n="FreeSpace / GB";e={($_.freespace / 1GB)}}
```

And you can delete credential key if you run powershell from user that have administrator permission at target computer